# How to capture rejected records in talend

Tags: talend, tmap

I have two tables called Product and Transactions.
In Product 19 records are there and in Transaction 21 records are there.

I am trying to get the matched records from both the tables using of Tmap (inner join).

I am able to load the matched records from the both tables, but I want to fetch the (unmatched records) into the rejected table.

I want to do this parallel in one job.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In your example, you're already catching the unmatched rows from products table using "catch inner join lookup rejects" option.. So what is it you're trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

Find the answer in the screen shots

[image]

[image]